# asp.net mvc 3 razor view -> strongly typed List of tuple problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, tuples

I'm having an odd problem with asp.net MVC razor view.

I want my model to be a `List<Tuple<string, int, int, int, int>>` which is perfectly valid in my other c# methods. But when I paste it into the `@model` declaration it seems to only pick out the string part of the tuple. So I have no ints. Only item1.

This problem is not present if I make it bind to a Tuple instead of the List.

Seems like the generated code is wrong, so perhaps this is a bug in razor view?

The error I get at compilation is:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected

Source Error:


Line 27:     
Line 28:     
Line 29:     public class _Page_Views_Dashboard_DestinationStatistics_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<List<Tuple<string {
Line 30:         
Line 31: #line hidden
```

To isolate this problem I did the following thing:

Create an empty asp.net mvc project. Create a new view. Past the following code.

```
@model List<Tuple<string, int, int, int, int>>

@foreach (var stat in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @stat.Item1
        </td>
        <td>
            @stat.Item2
        </td>
        <td>
            @stat.Item3
        </td>
        <td>
            @stat.Item4
        </td>
        <td>
            @stat.Item5
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I know I can just create a class or a struct to hold the data instead. Just asking out of curiosity

**EDIT:**
Solved and reported to the MVC team here http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8652

Comment: +1 what a cracking question - appears to be a bug in the Razor compiler. Trying it out myself I see the generated code is `public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::System.Tuple<string {`. (I've tried using the `global::` prefix to make it work). Looks like Razor parsing of the `@model` directive bunks after the first generic parameter.

Comment: @Andras Yeah, that's what I thought too. Seems like it's crashing at the fifth tuple parameter. 4 works

Comment: solved the problem. Doesn't mean you can use 5-parameter generics, though - there's a bug in `CodeTypeReference` - see my updated (and now trimmed) answer

Comment: If your model looks like `@model List<Tuple<string, int, int, int, int>>` it's really time to use a view model class and save your fellow programmers a headache in understanding your code! Tuples are a code-smell in this context.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*EDIT I've trimmed out some of the in-progress comments here - just view the history to see.*

So you can make this work with 1, 2, 3 or 4 tuple generic parameters but it doesn't work with 5.  As soon as you use 5 parameters it generates code like this:

```
 public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : 
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<List<System.Tuple<string {
```

I wanted to just find out if it's a character-length limitation, so I generated a class like this:

```
namespace ASP{  //same namespace that the backend code for the page is generated
  public class T { } 
}
```

And changed the model declaration:

```
@model List<Tuple<T,T,T,T,T>>.
```

In the end (see the history) I got to

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Tuple<T,T,T,T,T>>
```

Same problem!  It's not a problem with the @model keyword...

It took a while (reading through the MVC3 and Razor source, adding a couple of tests to that solution) - but here's a test that shows the why we get this error:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
  System.CodeDom.CodeTypeReferenceCollection c = 
    new CodeDom.CodeTypeReferenceCollection();
  c.Add("Tuple<T,T,T,T>");
  c.Add("Tuple<T,T,T,T,T>");
  //passes
  Assert.AreEqual("Tuple<T,T,T,T>", c[0].BaseType);
  //fails
  Assert.AreEqual("Tuple<T,T,T,T,T>", c[1].BaseType);    
}
```

So - the four-parameter version passes, but not the 5 parameter version.

And guess what- the actual value is `Tuple<T` - i.e. a truncated generic type name *truncated exactly the same way that you've observed in your code*.

Both the standard Razor parser and the Mvc Razor parser use the `CodeTypeReferenceCollection` type when parsing either the `@inherits` or `@model` keyword.  Here's the code for `@inherits` during code generation:

```
protected internal virtual void VisitSpan(InheritsSpan span) {
  // Set the appropriate base type
  GeneratedClass.BaseTypes.Clear();
  GeneratedClass.BaseTypes.Add(span.BaseClass);

  if (DesignTimeMode) {
    WriteHelperVariable(span.Content, InheritsHelperName);
  }
}
```

`GeneratedClass.BaseTypes` is a `CodeTypeReferenceCollection` - and `span.BaseClass` is a string.  Following that through in ILSpy, the offending method must be the private method `CodeTypeReference.Initialize(string typeName, CodeTypeReferenceOptions options)`.  I've not enough time now to figure out why it breaks - but then that's a Microsoft developer's job I think :) ***Update below - couldn't resist.  I now know where it's wrong***

### Bottom line

You can't use generics with more than 4 parameters in either Razor `@inherits` or `@model` statements (at least in C# - don't know about VB).  It appears that the Razor parser is incorrectly using the `CodeTypeReference` type.

### Final Update - or, I had the bit between my teeth :)

One of the things that `CodeTypeReference` does is strip off assembly name information from a passed type name with a call to the method `CodeTypeReference.RipOffAssemblyInformationFromTypeName(string typeName)`.

And of course, if you think about it - `Tuple<T,T,T,T,T>` is just like an assembly-qualified type name: With the type name = `Tuple<T`, Assembly = `T`, Version=`T`, Culture=`T`, PublicKeyToken=`T` (if you write a really BAD C# parser!).

Sure enough - if you pass in `Tuple<T,T,T,T,T,T>` as the type name - you actually get a `Tuple<T,T>`.

Looking deeper into the code, it's primed to receive a language-neutral typename (handles '[' but nothing for '<', for example) so, actually, the MVC team shouldn't just be handing the C# typename from our source straight through.

***The MVC team needs to change how they generate the base type*** - They could use the `public CodeTypeReference(string typeName, params CodeTypeReference[] typeArguments)` constructor for a new reference (instead of just relying on the `.Add(span.BaseClass)` creating it), and parse the generic parameters themselves since they know that the type name will be C#/VB style - not language-neutral .Net style with brackets etc as part of the actual name.

Comment: @Andreas Zoltan Gotta say, great work! Where can I report this to MS?

Comment: Hi @Oskar - you can do it here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio (submit a bug - not a suggestion :) ) since it's technically a bug in the .Net framework. But - you might actually be better off doing it direct to the MVC team through Codeplex: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781 (under 'Issue Tracker'). I reported one there and it was later fixed and updated.

Comment: @Oskar - definitely report it to the MVC3 team actually; they're not using the `CodeTypeReference` class correctly...

Comment: @Andras Will do! Really nice debugging

Comment: Hey @Oskar, thanks. It's a great question and one I've had a lot of fun unpicking! God I need to get a life! :)

Comment: @Andras this is **the** life. Most people just don't see that

Comment: Just ran into this too. Too bad you have to register on codeplex to vote, I guess that'll deter me.

Answer (score 8):

This has been through a few waves of discussion internally now and I'm afraid the final product is that we're not going to be able to fix this for Razor 2.0 (MVC 4). Let me give a little background on the reasoning.

First, it's important to note that the Razor parser *intentionally* parses the C# as little as possible. The main reason for this is to give you the freedom to the C# you want without us getting in the way. As a result (and you can verify this yourself now by checking out the code!) we do not parse type names in the `@inherits` and `@model` directives, we simply run until the end of the line. We are also the parsing engine behind the Razor editor, which means we have to support partially complete statements like `@model Foo<Bar` which is technically invalid but if you were typing `@model Foo<Bar>` this would be an expected intermediate step, so we should be able to handle it.

Now, we need to consider what would happen in we decided to change the way we generate code. As the [CodeTypeReference documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9347d8de.aspx) states, we would have to use `1[[ ... ]]` syntax to define the generic. However, we would still just be inserting whatever the user typed, so if you typed `@model Foo<Bar>` we'd tell CodeDOM that the base type was something like `` System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1[[Foo<Bar>]] ``. As you can see, we still end up with `<>` in the type name. As a result, we made the decision to use the fact that CodeDOM generally doesn't complain about `<>` and `(Of ...)` (in VB) syntax to hack our way around this problem.

Even parsing the whole type name you provided would be difficult given that we'd have to handle incomplete statements like `@model Foo<Bar, Baz`. In fact, it would also make the editor very brittle, since the editor actually depends on us being able to tell them exactly what range of Razor text maps to what range of C#/VB generated code, and if we introduce additional translation layers (such as the translation CodeDOM will be doing if we use `[]` or even the other overloads of the CodeTypeReference constructor) we can no longer make those assurances to the editor and you'll see strange behavior

So that leaves us with the workaround, which is to simply avoid using this many generic arguments. There are actually a number of reasons to avoid using Tuple in this way since using a custom model class would allow you to name the properties involved, and would give you greater flexibility when adding properties (with a tuple, you have to update the Controller and View when you want to add a "property" to your tuple). Having said that, we are keeping an eye on this issue and looking at how we can do a better job with this after 4.0. And now that we're open-source, we'd be happy to hear your suggestions and even accept your code!

Please don't hesitate to contact me (email is on my SO profile) or continue discussing this in comments if you have questions. I just wanted to give you the background context you deserve for having put so much excellent work into tracking this down!

-Andrew Nurse (Dev on Razor parser)

Comment: I know it's been a long time,  but thanks for this update, even if it's not what we wanted to hear :-)

Comment: faced this problem just now... is really THAT hard? Razor actually it's the smartest parser i've seen yet can't parse this ?? I'm shocked.

Comment: I second the recommendation to switch to a proper view model

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem today. I was returning some information about user activity, and had attempted to use a model definition of

```
@model List<Tuple<string,bool,DateTime,DateTime,DateTime>>
@* Name, Online, Created, Login, Active *@
```

The reason is that I am kind of tired of making single use classes for viewmodels, so that is why I do this for simple use. I received the same error as you. I attempted to bypass the error by using different combinations of tuples in the `@model` but to no avail.

What *did* end up working was to simply use the `ViewBag`. To note, the `model` is held in the `ViewBag` anyway so there isn't any issue using it in this capacity.

In my actionresult method, I simply assigned the list of tuples to a viewbag value

```
ViewBag.listTuple = listOfTuples;
```

and then in the view I cast i back

```
@{
    List<Tuple<string,bool,DateTime,DateTime,DateTime>> tuples = ViewBag.listTuple;
}
```

And that was that. Ran just fine. I am not saying this is the perfect solution but **it is a working workaround**.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might land here looking for the source of a CS1003 error in a Razor view, the CS1003 error is a general symptom of a failure by MVC to parse the Razor syntax.  It could be caused by many things, including the generic tuple problem above.

One thing I've noticed is that this problem will occur if you try to use a C# style single-line comment to annotate the model declaration in a Razor view:

```
BAD:  @model Int32 // user ID

GOOD: @* user ID *@
      @model Int32
```

Visual Studio syntax highlighting won't flag it as a problem, but it will fail at runtime.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem the question is about

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out that if you remove the @model directive, you won't have intellisense which actually who cares, but the view works perfectly with any number of tuple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem because I was using a `Tuple` of `Tuples`:

```
@model Tuple<Tuple<IEnumerable<int>, int, int>, Tuple<float, float, float>>
```

Needless to say, Razor did not like that. Anyway, I think it's interesting how the parses breaks on the total number of types, rather than the number of types at the top level object.

#### My workaround

I ended up going with a view model that simple created placeholders for the inside tuples:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Tuple<IEnumerable<int>, int, int> Models { get; set; }
    public Tuple<float, float, float> Selected { get; set; }
}
```

I'm happy I made the view model. It's more readable and (slightly) easier to manipulate and reason about inside the view.