# razor engine model declaration - Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

at the moment i'm trying to use multidimensional list with the razor engine in asp.net mvc 4.5
I think i have a Problem like [asp.net mvc 3 razor view -> strongly typed List of tuple problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098649/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view-strongly-typed-list-of-tuple-problem)

but there is no solution or Workaround... the line of code which returns the error "Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected"

```
@model List<Group2<string, Group<string, string, Group<string, string, ProductCatalogItem>>>>
```

and the models of Group + Group2

```
public class Group<K, L, T>
{
    public K Key;
    public L Name;
    public IEnumerable<T> Values;
}
public class Group2<K, T>
{
    public K Name;
    public IEnumerable<T> Values;
}
```

has anybody a Suggestion for me?

Comment: Holy abuse of generics, Batman!

Comment: you're right. bad solution... now i changed it - no generics and it works :-)