# MVC 5 @model Tuple bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, tuples

Is this a bug?

If I define in a view the model directive as :

```
@model Tuple<string,string,string,string>
```

it works great and I can use : @Model.Item1, @Model.Item2, @Model.Item3 and @Model.Item4.

if I define the model as :

```
@model Tuple<string,string,string,string,string>

the view returns error : CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected
```

Comment: "You can't use generics with more than 4 parameters in either Razor inherits or model statements" Source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098649/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view-strongly-typed-list-of-tuple-problem

Comment: Just wanted to point out that if you remove the @model directive, you won't have intellisense which actually who cares, but the view works perfectly with any number of tuple arguments.