# Kendo Grid Ajax Data binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement the Grid in ASP.NET MVC 5 app. I have use table in razor to test code and is pulling data properly, however i am trying to do server binding using provided Kendo helper classes but i am struggling to pull data to view. I am using Repository pattern and UnitOfWork.... the code is below ...

my 2nd question is, which is the best way to use Multiple Models in Single View???? I have also ViewModel but i havn't use in following code.. can i use @(Html.Kendo().Grid() and @(Html.Kendo().Grid() in same view... many thanks in advanced...

### Repository Class:

```
 public IEnumerable<FeeScheme> GetAllFeeScheme()
    {
        return getAllFeeSchemeFromRepository();
    }
```

### UnitOfWork class

```
  private IEnumerable<FeeScheme> getAllFeeSchemeFromRepository()
    {
        IEnumerable<FeeScheme> query = new List<FeeScheme>();

        query = (from b in _FeeScheme_Repository.GetAll()
                 select b).ToList();

        return query;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FeeScheme> GetAllFeeScheme()
    {
        return getAllFeeSchemeFromRepository();
    }
```

### Controller class

```
  public JsonResult GetAllFeeScheme([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {

        return Json(FeeScheme_UOF.GetAllFeeScheme().ToDataSourceResult(request));

    }
```

### View (Kendo )

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DatabaseLayer.TableMappings.FeeScheme>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
                 {
                     columns.Bound(c => c.FeeSchemeID);
                     columns.Bound(c=>c.FeeSchemeDescription);
                     columns.Bound(c => c.Fee);
                 })
                         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
            .Scrollable()
            .Groupable()
            .Sortable()
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                .Refresh(true)
                .PageSizes(true)
                .ButtonCount(5))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllFeeScheme", "Qualification"))
                .Model(model => model.Id(c=>c.FeeSchemeID))
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple question first:  To use multiple "view models" in a single view, you would do something like this:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public List<Object1> Object1List { get; set; }
    public List<Object2> Object2List { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        Object1List = new List<Object1>();
        Object2List = new List<Object2>();
    }
}
```

and then use the TestViewModel as the model for the view.

As far as changing your grid to server binding, it would look something like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<>(Model.Object1List)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
             {
                 columns.Bound(c => c.FeeSchemeID);
                 columns.Bound(c=>c.FeeSchemeDescription);
                 columns.Bound(c => c.Fee);
             })
                     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Server()
            .Model(model => model.Id(c=>c.FeeSchemeID))
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

**which is the best way to use Multiple Models in Single View**

First you can use one model that contains lists that you want like:

```
 public Model()
        {
        public Ilist < Model1 > Model1List
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        public IList < Model2 > Model2List
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
```

And second you can use [Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098649/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view-strongly-typed-list-of-tuple-problem)