# Syntax error, '>' expected in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, tuples

Ok, so I've been trying to pass multiple models to a View using a Tuple and it's worked like a charm so far. Problem comes when I try this

```
@model Tuple<Smart_WEB.Models.Room, List<IGrouping<string, Smart_WEB.Models.Song>>, List<IGrouping<string, Smart_WEB.Models.Video>>>
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBhIR.png)

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected
>
> Source Error:
>
> `Line 29:
>
>   Line 30:
>
>   Line 31:     public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Tuple<Smart_WEB.Models.Room {
>   Line 32:
>
>   Line 33: #line hidden`

And if I were to put something like:

```
@model Tuple<Smart_WEB.Models.Room, List<IGrouping<string, Smart_WEB.Models.Video>>>
```

Or

```
@model Tuple<Smart_WEB.Models.Room, List<IGrouping<string, Smart_WEB.Models.Song>>>
```

and the respective server side code it works perfectly.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me; I'm about to give up on this problem.

Comment: The `@model` differs entirely from your error. Are you sure you're looking at the right view?

Comment: oops. I was testing something and copied the worng error. Thanks! Already fixed it.

Comment: Is the comma actually a comma, not some higher Unicode character that looks like a comma?

Comment: And that's a correct number of angle brackets! Are you spanning model type over 2 lines of text?

Comment: I'm sure the comma is really a comma, wrote it four times and all four times it gave the same error. Even tried changing the number of item I pass to the Tuple (as seen in the other, working examples) and it appears to fail when there's three or more items that include Lists of IGrouping.

Comment: You don't have more than 4 items in your tuple but it seems to be exhibiting similar behavior to the issue with 5 items as described here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098649/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view-strongly-typed-list-of-tuple-problem

Comment: @stephen given the large number of generic arguments and the handling thereof you may still have a point. OP seems to have some MVC limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are basically passing multiple models in your view and MVC is designed to pass one type to one view, I strongly advise you to create a single model that wraps all your entities:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Smart_WEB.Models.Room Room { get; set; }
    public List<IGrouping<string, Smart_WEB.Models.Song>> Songs { get; set; }
    List<IGrouping<string, Smart_WEB.Models.Video>> Videos { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can set it as model in your view:

```
@model ViewModel
```

Comment: A `Tuple<>` _is_ one type, it just happens to be generic. That is fully supported by MVC. I agree that a viewmodel is a more sensible approach, but what OP shows, should just work.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, appreciate it! but more than using a workaround I would like to know what causes the error.

Comment: @Jairo - i don't see this as a workaround... ViewModel is the correct and proper way to use in scenarios such as yours. There are a few disadvantages and limitations with System.Tuple.. One of them is code readability - Model.Item1... Model.Item.. instead ViewModel is self-descriptive.. and other disadvantage is System.Tuple is not going well when you post data back from your View to Action.. i guess, that's not supported...